# ¿Como Enlazar datagird a una clase?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, c#-8.0

Tengo un datagirdview y la quiero enlazar con una clase pero no me aparece la solución

[image: datagirdview]

[image: aqui deberia estar la solucion del poryecto]

[image: clase]

[image: propiedades]

Comment: Cuantos proyectos tienes en tu solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Actualización]**

Revisando que es posible agregar una clase como Datasource, la posible causa de que no te aparezca ningún proyecto en esa ventana es que aún no hayas compilado la solución.

Sin embargo dejo el código anterior por si te es de utilidad.

Si deseas enlazar una lista de instancias de tu clase puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = class1list;
```

Donde "class1list" es una lista de instancias de "Class1".

Si deseas solo algunas propiedades, puedes usar Linq para pasar un objeto anónimo con las propiedades que necesitas, por ejemplo:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = class1list.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.ProductName }).ToList();
```

Comment: Tambien puedes hacerlo como lo esta pidiendo el usuario en su ejemplo, el problema que tiene el es que no sale informacion en la ventana q muestra, probablemente deba añadir otra referencia ya que quiza tenga dos proyectos, dentro de la misma solucion

Comment: Puede ser, aunque lo que entendí de la pregunta es que quiere enlazarlo a una clase, lo cual, hasta donde sé, no es posible desde el diseñador.

Comment: Si, si es posible desde el disennador

Comment: Interesante, investigaré un poco, gracias.

Comment: Hola Muchas Gracias

Comment: Con gusto, saludos.